# Partial Differential Equations for Image Inpainting - Gradients and Orthogonal to gradients

Tags: image-processing, gradient

I hope this is the correct channel. Following the Coursera course on image inpainting using PDEs [[1](https://www.coursera.org/learn/image-processing)], the instructor presents a method for image Inpainting that follows the next equation:

$\frac{\partial I}{\partial t} = \nabla (\Delta I) \cdot (\nabla I)^{\perp}$

where $I$ is the image, $\frac{\partial I}{\partial t}$ is the partial derivative of the Imgae w.r.t. time (i.e., iterations), and $ \Delta I = \frac{\partial I}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial I}{\partial y^2}$ the Laplacian of the image. Finally, the instructor mentions that $(\nabla I)^{\perp}$ is the orthogonal gradient of the image.

I am not sure if I understood it correctly, if I take $I(x,y)$, then $(\nabla I)^{\perp} = (-\frac{\partial I}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial I}{\partial x})$?

I have implemented this approach in Python as follows:

```
def create_images(shape):
    img_orig = 150*np.ones(shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    center = (shape[0]//2, shape[1]//4)
    [rr,cc] = disk(center, 50, shape=shape)
    img_orig[rr,cc] = 50
    center = (shape[0]//2, 3*shape[1]//4)
    [rr,cc] = disk(center, 50, shape=shape)
    img_orig[rr,cc] = 50

    # 0 -> intact
    # 1 -> corrupted-missing
    mask = np.zeros_like(img_orig)
    img = img_orig.copy()
    for k in range(15):
        [rr,cc] = ellipse_perimeter(img.shape[0]//2, 
                                    img.shape[1]//2, 
                                    50, 70-k)
        mask[rr,cc] = 1
        [rr,cc] = ellipse_perimeter(img.shape[0]//2, 
                                    img.shape[1]//2, 
                                    50-k, 70)
        mask[rr,cc] = 1
    noise = np.random.randint(0, 255, img.shape)
    img = img_orig*(1-mask) + mask*noise
    
    return img_orig, img, mask

def do_my_inpainting(img, mask, niter=10000, dt=.01, tol=1e-8):
    img_out = np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)
    img_out = np.array(cv2.GaussianBlur(img_out, (5,5), cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT), 
                        dtype=np.float64)
    img_out /= 255.
    diff = []
    for i in range(niter):
      gx, gy = np.gradient(img_out)
      gxx, _ = np.gradient(gx)
      _, gyy = np.gradient(gy)
      intensity = np.sqrt(gy**2 + gx**2 + 1e-15)
      nx, ny = gx/intensity, gy/intensity
      img_out += dt * (-lx*gy + ly*gx)
      a = np.linalg.norm(img_new.reshape(-1,1)-img_out.reshape(-1,1)) / np.linalg.norm(img_new.reshape(-1,1))
      if a < tol:
        break
    return img_out
```

The results are a complete disaster. Assuming that I have no bugs in the code, have I interpreted correctly the mathematics?